# Angular $watch is not called in directive controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

When I change value on scope within this "jstree" directive code(directives link function  - adds a plugin to redraw jstree nodes which adds buttons to every item in the tree with onclick for mode change):

```
 link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                        scope.selectedNode = scope.selectedNode || {};
                        scope.treeUrl = scope.treeUrl || 'treeUrl';
                        var treeElement = $(element);
                        var link = document.createElement('i');
                        //jstree plugin to rewrite node
                        $.jstree.plugins.noderewrite = function (options, parent) {
                           this.redraw_node = function (obj, deep, callback) {
                                obj = parent.redraw_node.call(this, obj, deep, callback);
                                if (obj) { //obj is listitem of the tree
                                    var tmp = link.cloneNode(true);
                                    tmp.href = "javascript:void(0)";
                                    tmp.className = "glyphicon-pencil";
                                    tmp.style = "cursor: pointer;";
                                    tmp.onclick = function () {
                                        scope.mode = "edit";
                                    }
                                    obj.insertBefore(tmp, obj.childNodes[2]);

                                    var tmp2 = link.cloneNode(true);
                                    tmp2.href = "javascript:void(0)";
                                    tmp2.className = "glyphicon-plus";
                                    tmp2.style = "cursor: pointer;";
                                    tmp2.onclick = function () {
                                        scope.mode = "add";
                                    }

                                    obj.insertBefore(tmp2, obj.childNodes[2]);
                                }
```

The watch code in the controller is not called:

```
var TreeController = [
            '$scope', 'stateService', '$timeout',
            function ($scope, stateService, $timeout) {
               $scope.treeUrl = "...";
               $scope.selectedTreeNode = {};
               $scope.mode = 'view';

                var previousSelection;

               $scope.watch('mode', function (name, oldVal, newVal) {
                   stateService.go(newVal);
               });
```

There is also a strange behavior between browsers. In firefox 36.0.1 (windows) everything works. In firefox can be used just $scope.watch without $, but in chrome I get error. The code in the watch is not called in chrome.
I tried deep watch, eg. watch with third param true, with no results.
Probably it is not a good idea to use watch, instead i should inject my state service into directive and use it directly instead of watch. Maybe I am just not doing it the Angular way.

Comment: $scope.watch('mode', function (newVal) {stateService.go(newVal)});

Comment: The definition of watch callback function params was also mystery for me, until i reaized that the first is the name. BTW I am using Angular 1.3.14

Comment: Do you have any plnkr/fiddle ?

Comment: $scope.$watch('mode', function (newVal) {stateService.go(newVal)});

Comment: @stepandohnal nope, the first parameter is the value returned by the watcher, and the second is the value previously assigned to the scope. The watcher doesn't have to be a simple model property, it could be a complex function. There is "name" for it.

Comment: Output from debugger in firefox: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UfwOl.png